# Im getting a "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'note' of undefined" error

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

Every answer for people getting the same error seems to be a different solution, I've been knocking my head against this problem for like a week. Finally decided to bite the bullet and ask for help

[Here is my html and Javascript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPMEW.png)

[Here is my CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEbI5.png)

Comment: It is appreciated if you can paste the code in the HTML/CSS snippet instead of images.

Comment: You are passing your `key` variable as `string` to `playNote()` function in your click event. Try passing the `key` variable directly like this: `playNote(key)`

Answer (score 0):

you wrote note instead of data-note in line 15 of html/js screenshot
Also, instead of binding event listeners to each element of that tag, try event delegation on the immediate root, which will be much more efficient than forEach